# Cumulative Subtraction in SQL

Tags: sql, dataframe, t-sql, datatables, calculation

I have the table where I have 2 values for each day. I need to subtract the Val1 + Val3 - Val2 row by row. E.g.:

```
          day   Val1    Val2  Val3
1    20230310    100     50   0
2    20230311    NaN     10   3
3    20230312    NaN      5   2
4    20230313    NaN     -3   1
5    20230314    NaN     40   0
```

How it should look like at the end:

```
          day   Val1    Val2  Val3
1    20230310    100     10    0
2    20230311     53     50    3
3    20230312     50      5    2
4    20230313     54     -3    1
5    20230314     14     40    0
```

Below is the same example but with the logic, not only the results:

```
          day   Val1        Val2  Val3
1    20230310    100         10    0
2    20230311    100-50+3=53   50    3
3    20230312    53-5+2=50      5    2
4    20230313    50-(-3)+1=54  -3    1
5    20230314    54-40=14     40    0
```

And I need to be this write in T-SQL.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the actual output based on your input data?

Comment: Is it always that the first value of `Val1` is not null and the rest values are null?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that the output should be like that and there is no other values in Val1 other than the first, the rest are always NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select *,
  isnull(val1,
    first_value(val1) over (order by day_) - 
    sum(case when val1 is null then val2 end) over (order by day_) + 
    sum(val3) over (order by day_)) as new_val1
from table_name
order by day_
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vNYkaffW)

Comment: It is working but the same as the previous answer there is an error with order, I've solve it adding ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING in the order, nevertheless  thank you for the answer

Comment: What is the datatype of the `day` column?

Comment: the type of the column day is nvarchar, but your solution shows correct output for my example.

Comment: Well, that is what caused the error of *... Largest size supported is 900 bytes*, it would be better to use the DATE datatype instead.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this? I guess there is something wrong with your output data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #myTable;

CREATE TABLE #myTable (
    day INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Val1 FLOAT,
    Val2 FLOAT,
    Val3 FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO #myTable (day, Val1, Val2, Val3)
VALUES 
    (20230310, 100, 50, 0),
    (20230311, NULL, 10, 3),
    (20230312, NULL, 5, 2),
    (20230313, NULL, -3, 1),
    (20230314, NULL, 40, 0);

SELECT *
     ,ISNULL(Val1, SUM(Val1) OVER (ORDER BY  [day]) - SUM(VAl2) OVER (ORDER BY  [day]) + SUM(VAl3) OVER (ORDER BY  [day]))
FROM #myTable
ORDER BY [day]
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is correct but I've got the error ORDER BY list of RANGE window frame has total size of 8000 bytes. Largest size supported is 900 bytes. And I have only 324 rows in the table.

Comment: I've just added ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING in the order and it is working, thanks

Comment: I see unfortunately now that there is a mistake that I do not know how to repair, in the second row the Val1 should be counted like that: Val1 from previous row - Val2+Val3 so it should be 100-50+3=43 and you have switched places 10 and 50 so the results are the same. In your example in row 2 result should be 100-10+3 = 93